# Adding custom query var to a single post without redirecting to its root slug

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules

I have created a post to posts relationship using ACF. On the single page of one of my CPTs I would like to add a prettified ID to the end of the slug to load different values on the page (`/my-archive/my-single-post/ID`) and have that ID saved to a query variable called custom_id. I also do not want the page to redirect to the original slug (`/my-archive/my-single-post/`).

I've managed to do the following:

```
add_action( 'init',  'add_custom_id_rewrite_rules' );
function add_custom_id_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^my-archive/([^/]*)/([0-9]+)?$', 'index.php?post_type=my_post_type&pagename=$matches[1]&custom_id=$matches[2]', 'top' );
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_custom_id_query_vars' );
function add_custom_id_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'custom_id';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

From everywhere I read, this should work. I've installed the Rewrite Rule Analyzer and it detects my custom_id correctly. However, despite it being considered correct I still get redirected to `/my-archive/my-single-post/`.

I want the query to still pull `the_title()` from that single post I just want to be able to query custom_id to change things on the page.

Thoughts?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, your rule would conflict with post pagination (`/my-archive/<post slug>/<page number>`), i.e. single posts with that are split to multiple pages using the `<!--nextpage-->` tag. Why not just set the post type's rewrite slug to `/my-archive/%postname%/%post_id%/` when you register your post type? Or you don't know how to do that? Can you show your post type registration code? Is `my-archive` actually a Page (post type `page`)?

Comment: `my-archive` is the slug given to the archive page of my CPT. I have a ton of records that I want to page so it's very possible that there's a conflict in rewrite rules but I've made sure to not have a conflict in the query variable names.

I'm not familiar with the `<!--nextpage-->` tag and I'm not sure I understand what you mean by defining the rewrite slug to my posts. The individual posts are just fine, I just want to add my fake pages at the end of the slug without redirecting. Will any integer at the end of the URL conflict? I ask because I tried adding to the URL to distinguish the 2

Comment: "Will any integer at the end of the URL conflict" - yes. More specifically, if the post has the `<!--nextpage-->` tag, e.g. `Page 1<!--nextpage-->Page 2`, then on page 2, WordPress won't recognize the page number because it became the value of the `custom_id` instead. See [`wp_link_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_link_pages/) and the [Page Break block](https://wordpress.org/support/article/page-break-block/).